# SQL Server 2014 Express install fails on Windows 7 "Version string portion was too short or too long.."

Tags: sql-server, windows

When I try to install `SQL 2014 Express on Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise` it fails with error "SQL Server 2014 Express install fails on `Windows 7 with "   SQL Server Setup` has encountered the following error:

> Version string portion was too short or too long.

Googling gave me some leads where cause of this issue might be old SQL Server versions floating around. So uninstalled all the SQL Server related tools and registry entries. But still get this error.

Any ideas friends?

Comment: Not without specifics. There is no incompatibility between 2014 Express and Windows 7. You may have a corrupted iso or exe.

Comment: Do you know what Version string portion... means in this context?

Comment: What string portion? You haven't posted any logs or error messages. It's impossible to guess what's wrong with *your* machine. Not without logs

Comment: Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: System.ArgumentException
    Message: 
        Version string portion was too short or too long.
    HResult : 0x80070057
    Data: 
      HelpLink.EvtType = 0xEE6077BB@0x294A9FD9
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at System.Version..ctor(String version)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.MsiProductProvider.get_Version()